# Why isn't transition getting registered as an element in html?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

```
<template>
<header>
<nav class="container">
    <div class="branding">
        <router-link class="header" :to="{name : 'Home'}">>FireBlogs</router-link>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Home</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Blogs</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Create Post</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Login/Register</router-link>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<menuIcon class="menu-icon" />
    <transition name="mobile-nav" id="mobile-nav">
        <ul>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Home</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Blogs</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Create Post</router-link>
            <router-link class="link" to="#">Login/Register</router-link>
        </ul>
    </transition>
</header>
</template>
```

In this vueJS code I have some elements inside the transition tag, but when I inspect the web page I can only see this:
[Console Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wbz5t.png)
I wish to style the transition tag as a whole using CSS. Can somebody help me figure this out?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! The `transition` tag doesn't render an element. It's meant to define transitions/changes of states of elements _within_ the tag. What you could do is use [`TransitionGroup`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#differences-from-transition) instead and pass a `tag` attribute to render an actual element *or* you could simple style using `header > ul { styles here }`

Comment: Thanks Sir for your help, Now I am able to style it. I have just started learning about VueJS and this was little problematic, but your answer saved me time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an answer since this is getting some upvotes:

`transition` elements do not create a DOM element, they define transitions/changes of states to elements *within* the tag.

To create a DOM element that can be targeted with CSS, you can use [`TransitionGroup`](https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#differences-from-transition) and then use the `tag` property to render a wrapping element:

`<TransitionGroup tag="div">{stuff here}</TransitionGroup>`

If you don't want to create another element, but keep the `transition` element, you can use the parent element to style.

```
header > ul { styles here }
```